# Disable enable check boxs via selection of combo boxs values using javascript

Tags: javascript

My html table have many rows.One checkbox and one combo box have contained per each row. When I select combo box and get one value then disable checkbox for relative row according to check combo box value.Here is my javascript method

```
    function check(cbo) {
    var chx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for ( var i = 0; i < chx.length; i++) {
        if (chx[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            chx[i].disabled = (cbo.value == 'D') ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

My requirement is when I select combo box and disable enable checkbox for each row.Please share me something.

Comment: A fiddle would be more explaining..http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a dynamic id (number) and append id with your select and checkbox, as following:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Row - 1</td>
    <td>
        <select id="select1" 
            onchange="checkTheCheckbox('select1', 'check1');">
            <option value="false" selected="true">Default</option>
            <option value="true">Check</option>
            <option value="false">Uncheck</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row - 2</td>
    <td>
        <select id="select2" 
            onchange="checkTheCheckbox('select2', 'check2');">
            <option value="true" selected="true">Default</option>
            <option value="true">Check</option>
            <option value="false">Uncheck</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" checked />
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Add following javascript method:

```
function checkTheCheckbox(selectId, checkId){
    var ddl = document.getElementById(selectId);
    for(var i= 0; i < ddl.length; i++){
        if(ddl[i].selected){
            var status = ddl[i].value === 'true' ? true : false;
            document.getElementById(checkId).checked = status;
        }
    }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gRAb6/

Answer (score 0):

Using an object's `parentNode`, you can find a shared parent  of both the checkbox and the combo box (probably the `tr` table-row element), and then select within that row for the element you want.  Something like:

```
function check(cbo) {
    var parent = cbo.parentNode;
    var chx = parent.getElementByTagName('input');
    ...
}
```

it may make things a lot simpler for you to use some classes to make selection easier as well.  For instance, giving all the checkboxes that you want to be able to be disabled the class of `"checkbox_will_disable"`, say, will allow you to use the `document.getElementsByClassName` function, which means you don't need the `if chx[i].type == "checkbox"` any more.

the end function could become something like:

```
function check(cbo) {
    var parent = cbo.parentNode;
    var chx = parent.getElementByClassName('checkbox_will_disable');
    for (var i=0; i < chx.length; i++) {
        chx[i].disabled = (cbo.value == 'D') ? true : false;
    }
}
```

if the `parentNode` of the `cbo` isn't far enough up the chain (say it's a `td` rather than the `tr` or something) you can keep on using it until you're far enough up:

```
var parent = cbo.parentNode.parentNode;
```

say.  There are also more elegant ways to do these kinds of things, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), for instance.  And if it becomes complex enough, you may find it easier switching to a javascript framework such as [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Good luck!